# How do I delete users that have uid 0?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, system-administration, etcpasswd

I am supposed to clear all users that have the ID of 0 other than root.  For example, my passwd file contains a user root with ID 0 and a user homer with ID 0.

I tried something like

```
grep :x:0: passwd | grep -v root:x: | awk -F : '{ print $1 }' | xargs userdel
```

but I received error userdel: user homer is currently logged in even though I am logged in as root, not homer.  This error comes from them sharing and ID, I presume.

Is there any way around this?  Should I just edit the passwd and shadow files?  Otherwise, is there a way to force id 0 to be unique so that we can guarantee no other users will be created with id 0?  Thanks.

Comment: UIDs *are* unique. You don't have two users with ID = 0, you have two usernames for the user with ID = 0. Your command is asking `userdel` to delete that user (via its username `homer`), which you can't do because you were logged in as that user (via its username `root`).

Comment: OK thanks. Is there a way to delete the other usernames? Is removing the lines from passwd and shadow all that is necessary?

Comment: See below for the right command.  Editing directly is dangerous on a machine with any load.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"homer" and "root" are the same account.  You can have multiple usernames for a single account.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49993/another-account-with-same-uid-as-root-gets-prompted-to-set-new-password-for-root

You'll want `vipw` and `vipw -s` to fix this.  Editing directly with `vim` or `sed` is a bad idea.

Consider https://serverfault.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ for future questions of this type.

Answer (score 3):

This is a trick: 
`userdel -rf username`

This command shows you:

```
userdel: user XXX is currently used by process 1
```

but username has removed

Answer (score 2):

You can have this sed command:

```
sed '/^[^:]\+:x:0:/{/^root:/!d}' /etc/passwd
```

Or

```
sed -i '/^[^:]\+:x:0:/{/^root:/!d}' /etc/passwd
```

Which would modify the file.